# SFML sprite movement system using key pressed events not working

Tags: c++, sfml

```
while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
    if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed) {
        if (event.key.code == Keyboard::D)
            moright == true;
        if (event.key.code == Keyboard::A)
            moleft == true;
    }

    if (event.type == Event::KeyReleased) {
        if (event.key.code == Keyboard::D)
            moright == false;
        if (event.key.code == Keyboard::A)
            moleft == false;
    }

    if (moright == true) {
        sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(5.f, 0.f));
        moright == false;
    }

    if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        window.close();
}
```

Works with no errors but sprite doesn't move when I press D. Very new to c++ and sfml so apologies if this a stupid question and for my messy code.

Comment: `=` for assignment as opposed to `==`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first and second outer `if` you probably meant `moright = true`, `moleft = true`, same with `= false`.

The `==` currently written there just compares `moright` (or `moleft`) with `true` (in the first `if` pair) or with `false` (in the second one) without changing any values.